# Changing startup page at run time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In a VS2010 ASP.Net website is it possible to alter the 'Specific Page' at project start up? Basically our startup page requires todays date to be passed in as a query string to prevent people from permanently bookmarking the page.

Obviously this causes headaches for developers as they have to manually change the date  on their startup page every day. Is there any way of automatically changing the query string either by using an environment variable of some kind or a build event? Currenty our Start Action is set to:
Specific Page: Example.aspx?date=**18/04/2011**
it is the part in bold I would like to change when starting the project.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
void OnBeginRequest()
{
#if DEBUG
    if(Request.Url.Host == "localhost" && Request["date"] == null)
        Redirect(Request.Url + "?date" + DateTime.Today);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is to create a page (temp.aspx), set the page as the startup page, and in the page_load event redirect the user to the new page. like this

```
response.redirect("Example.aspx?date=" + system.datetime.now.toshortdatestring());
```

Comment: I did think about this but then the temp page would need deleting from the production site when we release (unless there is an automated way of doing this?).